# Iterate over Properties of an Operator

Tags: python, properties

I'd like to iterate over the properties (names and values) of a dialog operator in its execute method.

My current way of doing this involves a metaclass and multiple inheritance...

Is there any simpler way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To iterate over all RNA properties you can access:

`self.rna_type.properties.keys()`,

In most cases you'll want to skip `rna_type`, which is added automatically.

---

Example operator which prints its properties in order.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Operator"

    foo = StringProperty()
    bar = StringProperty()
    baz = StringProperty()
    spam = StringProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        for k in self.rna_type.properties.keys():
            if k == "rna_type":
                continue
            print(k)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```